# The Navigation Architecture Component with bottom navigation view. How to achieve YouTube like navigation?

Tags: android, android-architecture-components, android-architecture-navigation

I want to use the new Navigation Architecture Component.

Every time we switch tabs in bottom navigation view, the backstack is cleared on fragment we came from.

For example we have two tabs.

***Tab 1: A 

 Tab 2: B***

When we navigate from **A** to **C** (detail fragment in tab 1) then switch tab to **B** the backstack of tab 1 is cleared. Therefore when we go to tab 1 we will see new instance of **A**.

Can you help with this?

Thank you

Comment: Before you detach a fragment you can save its state using [`FragmentManager.saveFragmentInstanceState`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentManager#saveFragmentInstanceState(android.support.v4.app.Fragment)). And before you attach that fragment later you can reset previously saved state using [`Fragment.setInitialSavedState`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/Fragment.html#setInitialSavedState(android.support.v4.app.Fragment.SavedState)). `Fragment.SavedState` implements `Parcelable` so you can even put it into a `Bundle`.